# How to specify the target location for downloading the remote file using mget command?

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

I have a batch file to do the bulk copy the file from remote location. This is working fine. But here I want to specify the local system location (target location).

Sample:

```
 cd test/test
 mget sample_*.zip
 quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `lcd /path` to change the current local working directory:

```
cd /source_remote_path
lcd /destination_local_path
mget sample_*.zip
quit
```

See the [`ftp` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp).

If you are running Windows locally, use Windows style path, of course:

```
lcd c:\destination_local_path
```

See the [Windows `ftp.exe` `lcd` command help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-lcd).